How to Generate x-hm authentication token for use with HCX APIs
I am trying to migrate virtual machines from on-premises vSphere 6.7 with vSS to Google Cloud VMware Engine using HCX.
However, despite the fact that the ping between HCX Connector and HCX manager passes and the name resolution from HCX Connector to HCX manager is working, the site pairing is not succeeding at all.
The error message is as follows.

Error connecting to remote site A JSONObject must begin with '{' at character 0 of

After investigating the cause, I found the KB, so I executed Method 2, but the line "x-hm-authorization" does not exist in the execution result.
enter image description here
It also throws the following error
enter image description here
How can I generate the "x-hm-authorization" token?
